# Conda windows close after execution of simple commands

Tags: python, anaconda

Trying to run very basic commands like conda envs list opens a new window, which then closes immediately.

I am running Python 3.7 on Windows 10 installed with Anaconda. I swear to god I found a fix for this a few months ago then lost it.

NB: update and install commands still work, and wait for input as expected. This is driving me crazy and I'm sure its something goofy, please help!

Comment: You need to be way more specific about what the problem is and what you're trying to do. Please reduce it to one case that works (and show that, with code) and one case that doesn't (with code, please). Also, Python 3.7 only exists as a developer version, so are you sure that's the right version?

Comment: With cmd open, if I run "conda install numpy" a new window will open where conda runs, and waits for the input of "y/n"

On completion, the window closes immediately. On commands such as "activate tensorflow" when the new window opens, it closes immediately, and I cannot work within the env.

Comment: That is very strange, I've never heard of it spawning a new CMD window...

Comment: Yeah it's really starting to irk me; the worst part is, like I said, I swear I had found a workaround for this a few months ago. On my other machines it works fine (especially with the terminal in the newest Windows 10 builds which I am sorely missing on this machine!).

Do you have any idea if it could be some strange system-level setting that can be tweaked? I'll try and disable antivirus etc. in case their is some strange behavior where it stops commands being run inline but that seems a bit overboard...